# How to block messages from being printed in active ttys?

Tags: tty

Due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925760), I get text messages messing up my ttys every minute.
The messages appear on any tty, even before logging in; but only when the tty is active.
It's worst when I am using whole-screen applications such as emacs, vim or aptitude.

Is it possible to get rid of these annoying, intrusive, misplaced warnings?

I use Ubuntu 12.04. (But it sounds like it's a Linux core problem, as Arch Linux and Debian also have this bug) on a Dell Vostro laptop.

Comment: The bug you quoted mentions a workaround which blacklists the module that generates those entries (see comment #75). Have you tried that?

Comment: My bad, you are right! I didn't. I'll do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent text messages from poping into actives ttya, you may just add `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. (Or just uncomment the line if it appears contained in a comment)

Here is the top of my `/etc/sysctl.conf`, since I did so:

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As ***roadmr*** noticed me, a workaround is already mentioned in [the page I linked in my question](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925760), among the comments :

***Comment #8, by Neal McBurnett (nealmcb)  :***

> 2 WORKAROUNDS: I can at least get it to shut up by doing "`sudo rmmod ums_realtek`"
>
> If I subsequently do a "`sudo modprobe ums_realtek`" the messages start
>   showing up again every 52 seconds.
>
> If I actually try use the sdb device (which is the SD card in my dell
>   mini 1012 netbook) by inserting an SD card, the card seems to work
>   fine - it automatically reloads the module and mounts the card.
>
> And, in addition, inserting a card also makes the messages go away,
>   even after the card is removed, and even though ums_realtek remains
>   loaded.

***Comment #75 by Krzysztof Kosinski (tweenk) :***

> For a permanent workaround, create the file
>   `/etc/modprobe.d/ums-realtek.conf` with the following content:
>
> ```
> options ums_realtek ss_en=0
> ```
>
> or execute this command:
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c 'echo "options ums_realtek ss_en=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/ums-realtek.conf'
> ```